# Where is pages_read_engagement in instagram approve procedure?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

After instagram api updates - I need make review of my app to login throht instagram.
In approve block, instagram notify me:

**Before you can submit for review, complete the following:**
**Your submission must include pages_read_engagement to use instagram_basic.**

Can somebody explain, where I can include pages_read_engagement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find solution, it means you need add from App Review -> Requests section
**Add additional permissions and features** "pages_read_engagement" - permission.